# Make a Unity 3D body move in a circle from it's launch point?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

I'm playing with some Unity code to expand my horizons.

I have the following code, which launches a bullet from the character that flies in a direction set by 'this.angle' which is the angle the gun is pointing to the target.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to make the bullet leave the gun and travel 360 degrees right around and shoot the player (actually the gun really) from behind.

I'm not fully understanding quarternions, but I don't think I need to, to solve this.

Could someone please give me a pointer?

```cs
base.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, Mathf.MoveTowardsAngle(base.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, this.angle, 9.3f * Time.deltaTime), 0f);
Vector3 cposition = base.transform.position;
base.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(base.transform.position, cposition, Time.deltaTime * 2f);
this.pos.set(base.transform.position);
this.rot.set(base.transform.rotation);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so if you want to stick with your original idea, you could make it like this:

Code for the bullet

```
void Update(){

transform.Rotate(degTurnRate, 0, 0);
transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * bulletSpeed

}
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this, with great thanks, although it wasn't exactly right it did lead me to the exact solution: ```base.transform.Rotate(0f, this.turnRate * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
base.transform.position += base.transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * this.bulletSpeed;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the code much simple if you just use the [Transform.RotateAround](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html)
this enables you to rotate the object around the specified targt for the x amount on any of the axes.

Comment: I guess that assumes I have a target to rotate around; I'd looked at this and dismissed it because I'd have to create an object or a point in 3d space at the centre of the circle that the bullet would travel. 

When in fact, the bullet is given a forward velocity and a maximum turn 'rate' and would thus calculate on the fly what it's centre of the circular path would be. I guess I was looking for a way to force it to keep turning, rather than turn to an angle and stop.

Comment: Well by that logic you can 'define' your turn radius by variably setting the pivot position for the run around (set it further from the gun for larger turn radius)

Comment: I see what you're saying. My problem lies with the fact that the turn radius coded into all this is only defined by a 'rate of turn' per frame; thus I don't know how to calculate the circle or the centre of the circle myself ahead of time.  I was hoping to find a way within the Quaternion.Euler or transform methods to apply a contant turn to an object, such that it worked it's own circle out (given the rate of turn) and thus would come back around and shoot the shooter.

Comment: well, if you have a rate of turn, what is that defined in terms of? degrees? percentage of 360 per frame? you should be able to work out the size of the circle from that